# How do you feel vs How are you feeling

Tags: idiomatic-language, stative-verbs

Is there a subtle difference in meaning or usage between `How do you feel` and `How are you feeling`?

I could use these to ask about someone's health, state of mind or about their opinion on something.

Similarly, when asking about someone's senses are both `What are you feeling` and `What do you feel` acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider that *How are you feeling?* is asking about someone's health or wellbeing, and *How do you feel [about X]?* is asking for their opinion.